# Uploading Image to folder while inserting filename in database Asp.net C# SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image, upload

so started using a new method for dynamicly displaying images inserted into my database. This is the asp.net code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval ("ImageUrl", "~/img/{0}") %>' Width="200px" PostBackUrl='<%#Eval ("ProductID", "Product.aspx?ProductID={0}") %>' runat="server" />
```

now, as you can see what it does is getting the "ImageUrl" from my database depending on what the ProductID is, and then shows that as the image url. Example in my folder /img/ i have a picture called "pic.jpg" then this code would make the image url "~/img/Pic.jpg" now how would i add a new image into the table from the backend? i would have to make a flileupload control upload the file to the "img" folder and then insert only the file name as the "ImageUrl" in the database table. How is this done? do you have any examples or can point me in the right direction?

thanks!

all answers appreciated!

Comment: Dont Mind This: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="alle" Selected="True"/>
            </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: using DataSetTableAdapters;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ProductTableAdapter myProduct = new ProductTableAdapter();
    CategoriesTableAdapter myCategory = new CategoriesTableAdapter();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

Comment: ListView2.DataSource = myProduct.GetData();
            ListView2.DataBind();
            DropDownList2.DataSource = myCategory.GetData();
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "CategoryID";
            DropDownList2.DataBind();

        }
    }

Comment: protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "0")
        {
            ListView2.DataSource = myProduct.GetData();
            ListView2.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ListView2.DataSource = myProduct.GetDataByCategoryID(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue));
            ListView2.DataBind();

        }
    }
}

Comment: Kode for ImageUpload:

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + filename);
                Label1.Text = ("File Was Uploaded");
                string strFilename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                string FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
                Label2.Text = filename;

Comment: }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Validation Link: http://articlemirror.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-validate-textbox-using.html

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426761/Exploring-ASP-NET-Validation-Controls

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton is actually a html input type image. So you should not use it for just display purposes. You can use Image control or even use html img tag.

Check this link for FileUpload control

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

Check this link for Image control

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_image